# Private Endpoint in ACI not available for germanywestcentral?

Tags: networking, azure-container-instances, vnet

I am facing a issue that containers which should only have private endpoints cannot be deployed
"The requested resource is not available in the location 'germanywestcentral' at this moment. Please retry with a different resource request or in another location. Resource requested: '1' CPU '1.5' GB memory 'Linux' OS virtual network"

The same container is working is fine as soon as I select public interface.

I didn't find anything about it in documentation or internet, so maybe someone here has an idea?

Thanks in advance
Stefan

Comment: Hi RahulKumarShaw. Sorry to say but it did not help because public interface is working fine and only private endpoint did not work, so it cannot be about ressources but about something else.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with QuickStart Image and DockerHub Registry as well getting the same result.

[image]
[image]

This error indicates that due to heavy load in the region in which you are attempting to deploy, the resources specified for your container can't be allocated at that time. Use one or more of the following mitigation steps to help resolve your issue.

1.Deploy to a different Azure region

2.Deploy at a later time

3.You can also reach out to [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for details information.

Refernce : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/394616/trying-to-re-deploy-a-container-instance-but-error.html

Comment: Hi RahulKumarShaw,
I am facing this issue since months now and did not find any limitation about private networks in westgermany. Also another region is a problem because all my service (like SQL) are running in westgermany which makes it "impossible" to connect to them. 
At least I would require a Support Plan purchased and I thought (as it is a general issue) someone else also must face this issue. Thats the reason why I am asking here :)
Thanks in anyway for trying out the deployment

Comment: for few location you have to raise a quota request from support .Its is limitation from MS end . Then only can deploy the ACI in this location.

Comment: Some regions don't support availability zones (denoted by a 'N/A' in the table below),Please check this MS document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability